# Bounty award when owner answer and accept his answer with score 2

Tags: support, bounty

I read [How is a bounty awarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), but I confuse in some case.

In the case of, owner did not accept an answer that score 2(by other user), but he accept his answer with score 2.

In this case, who got his bounty when bounty period is end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers posted by the person setting the bounty are never eligible for a bounty. This also applies to automatic awarding!

The automatic bounty will go to the answer that is either:

- Not created by the bounty setter, has been posted after the bounty started and was marked as accepted (by the bounty setter) during the bounty period. It'll be awarded the full bounty.
- Not created by the bounty setter, has been posted after the bounty started, and has the highest score (at least a score of 2 or up). It'll be awarded half the bounty.

It doesn't matter here if the bounty setter accepted their own answer, if there is another answer that has a score of 2 or higher, it'll get half the bounty.

Comment: Are you really sure a post cannot qualify during the grace-period? Because the help-center seems to think so.

Comment: @Deduplicator answers posted in the grace period do qualify.